# Is this bounded

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, combinatorics, geometry, analysis

Let $d_{k}$ be supremum of the minimum of the pairwise distances between any
$k$ points in the unit square. Is $kd_{k}$ bounded as $k\rightarrow\infty$ ?

Comment: Any helpful answers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is this homework? or are you just curious

Comment: @RustynYazdanpour: This is not homework.

Comment: @diana does in mean within the circle, or do you only allow for the perimeter? if the later, you are right that it is sufficient to consider the unit circle, in which case $\lim kd_k = 2 \pi $ hence is bounded.

Comment: @CalvinLin Would you please be able to offer a proof of why $d_k = 2\pi / k$? While it's certainly intuitive (in the sense that in makes sense for the maximal solution is to have points spread out in a regular n-gon) and I assume any proof would be via contradiction, I can't think of an exact reason for why.

Comment: To make it easier, one can consider the unit disk instead. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewD That comment was made assuming it was the circle, not the disk. I've added how to deal with the disk.

Comment: @CalvinLin Ah, I see.

Answer (score 1):

The centered hexagonal numbers have the form $3k(k+1) + 1$. This allows us to place $3k(k+1) + 1$ points whose minimum distance apart is $\frac{1}{k-1}$.

Thus, for $n = 3k(k+1) + 1$, $d_n \geq \frac{1}{k-1}, $ which gives $ n d_n \geq \frac{ 3k(k+1)+1}{k-1} > 3k $. Hence, the sequence is unbounded.

In fact, this shows that for $\alpha > \frac{1}{2}$, $ n^ \alpha d_k$ is unbounded.

---

This was scratch work to motivate that the sequence is unbounded. It calculates an upper bound for $d_n$.

Fix $n$. we want to calculate an $r$ such that we will find 2 points distance at most $r$ apart.

Consider circles of radius $\frac{r}{2}$ about each point. These fall within a circle of radius $1+\frac{r}{2}$ If any of the small circles overlap, we have our 2 points. Hence if

$$ n r^2 < (2 +r)^2 \Rightarrow (n-1)r^2 - 4r - 4 < 0,$$

then we can find 2 points that are within $r$ of each other. We can solve this for $r$ to get $ r = \frac {4 + \sqrt{ 16+4(n-1)}} {2(n-1)} $

This strongly suggests that $nr$ is unbounded, and in fact grows like $\sqrt n$. At this point, I'd suggest finding constructions that look like honeycomb packing.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but what configuration achieves the  bound $1/\sqrt{n}$ for $d_n$? Thanks!

Comment: @diana As stated in the answer, the hexagonal packing achieves a bound of approximately $\sqrt{ \frac{3}{n} } $.